Warning failed to resolve include moc_predefs.h - VS2022 Qt5.15.2
I have a project written in Visual Studio 2022 c++ with Qt5.15.2 (x64).
It comiles and works just fine.
During compilation I get a warning for each widget-derived-class in my project.
Moc'ing DlgLoadSegment.h...
1>Moc'ing DlgLogin.h...
1>Moc'ing DlgMandant.h...
1>Moc'ing DlgOptionOutput.h...
1>Moc'ing DlgOptions.h...
1>Moc'ing DlgProjectNavigation.h...
1> Warning: Failed to resolve include "Debug/moc_predefs.h" for moc file D:\_KKP_2022\K2\WidgetWebApp.h
1>Moc'ing DlgSaveSegment.h...
1> Warning: Failed to resolve include "Debug/moc_predefs.h" for moc file D:\_KKP_2022\K2\DlgAddFilling.h

So I was just wondering, does anyone of you know how to get rid of this warning?
I do not any code number to suppress the warning, also I am not aware that I use the (probably) autogenerated "moc_predefs" header.

I think I found the solution.
In the project setting there was an include in the moc-settings. I emptied that entry and the warning disapeared.

